# Band rerendering netcdf file by variable not time. Using gdal, nco, cdo

Tags: gdal, netcdf, average

I want to average netcdf data (band1: precipitation) in bins (i.e. 0.01,0.10,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0, etc.). What nco, gdal, or nco tools can I use to regrid the netcdf file this way?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. what are the dimensions in your netcdf file? Are you trying to bin the data at 1 moment in time (i.e. spatially) or does your netcdf contain a timeseries and you want to bin that? So you are trying to create a histogram?